# Segmentation Fault while using rand() on C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I've been getting an error while trying to pass a struct array to a function and assigning it random values

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    time_t t; //Variable t is of the type time - this allows us to store date&time
}
train;

int setTrainDetails();

int main() {
    train array[10]; // initializing first array
    setTrainDetails(array[10].id);
}

int setTrainDetails(train array[10]) {
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10) {
        array[count].id = rand() % 100 + 100; // set train number from 100-200
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read (both for yourself and for other people) if you used consistent indentation. I have edited your question in order to fix it.

Comment: You should provide proper prototypes: `int setTrainDetails();` Why don't you specify correct parameter list? You hinder the compiler from telling you that arguments don't match

Comment: What you actually do is: Access `array[10].id` which is an out of bounds access on that array and pass that integer to a function that expects to get a pointer to an array. If you did not crash until that point, that `int` will be treated as an address. More crashes ahead....

Comment: It also may be worth noting that `srand()` should only be called once, so if `rand()` will only appear in `setTrainDetails()` then the code is fine as written, but if `rand()` will be used elsewhere it may make more sense to call `srand()` right before `setTrainDetails()` is called as part of the initialization process in `main()`

Answer (score 3):

Your function prototype for `setTrainDetails()` should include the type of the input parameter. This is basically a stylistic difference from the code you provided, but it will allow the compiler to help you find type-mismatch bugs:

```
int setTrainDetails(train array[]);
```

Then when you call `setTrainDetails()` in `main()`, you should pass a pointer to the entire array. C arrays decay into pointers when passed to a function, so you can just pass `array`:

```
train array[10]; // Declaring first array
setTrainDetails(array);
```

Passing `array[10].id` is undefined behavior, because `array` is only 10 `train`s long, and C arrays start at index 0, so `array[0]`-`array[9]` are valid but `array[10]` is no good.

`train array[10];` declares an array of type `train` that is 10 `train`s long, but once the array is declared, `array[10]` means index-10-of-the-array, which is out of bounds. Furthermore, your function `setTrainDetails()` expects a `train` array parameter, so even if `array[10].id` was valid, the `.id` member of `train` is an `int`.

Inside the `while` loop of `setTrainDetails()` you have this line:

```
array[count].id = rand() % 100 + 100; // set train number from 100-200
```

which actually sets train number to a pseudo-random number between 100-199, since `rand() % 100` can only return integers 0-99. for random numbers between 100-200 *inclusive*, you would want `rand() % 101 + 100`

Outside of that your code is fine

Comment: This is one of the reasons I always recommend putting the definition of the called function before its caller (if both are in the same source file) - i.e., defining `setTrainDetails` before `main`.  It's one less opportunity to make this kind of mistake.